Using primitive recursion for defining a function of one argument
I have a problem with some details of the proof that the predecessor function is a primitive recursive function -- in particular with how primitive recursion operation is used here.
Primitive recursion is the following operation: it takes $g : \mathbb{N}^k \to \mathbb{N}$ and $h: \mathbb{N}^{k+2} \to \mathbb{N}$, and returns $f : \mathbb{N}^{k+1} \to \mathbb{N}$ such that
$$ f (x_1, \ldots, x_k, 0) = g(x_1, \ldots, x_k)$$
$$ f (x_1, \ldots, x_k, S(y)) = h (x_1, \ldots, x_k, y, f(x_1, \ldots, x_k, y)). $$
The predecessor function is defined by
$$pred (0) = 0$$
$$pred(S(y)) = y$$
Since we have two clauses in this definition, it looks like we need primitive recursion here (we cannot obtain such two clauses by means of the other operation -- i.e., composition). However, the definition of the predecessor does not exactly fit the above scheme. This is because in that scheme, $g$ needs to have at least one argument and $f$ at least two arguments (if $k \geq 1$), whereas in the definition of the predecessor, $f$ has one argument and $g$ has zero arguments.
(1) Is this impression correct and in the definition of primitive recursion we indeed can have $k=0$? If so, how are such functions with zero arguments formally (i.e., set-theoretically) defined?
(2) Alternatively, is there some trick that allows one to obtain $pred$ by using the operation of primitive recursion without taking $k=0$?

There are different conventions, sometimes the case $k = 1$ is treated with a separate definition where $f(0) = c$ for some constant, and sometimes we indeed consider functions with $k = 0$ (nullary functions).
The definition of a nullary function is the same as in other arity. $\mathbb{N}^0$ is the set of all tuples of natural numbers with length $0$. There is exactly one length $0$ tuple, namely, $()$. So a nullary function $g \colon \mathbb{N}^0 \to \mathbb{N}$ is defined by exactly one value $c = g()$, and vice versa, every constant $c \in \mathbb{N}$ defines a nullary function $g$ such that $g() = c$. Hence nullary functions $\mathbb{N}^0 \to \mathbb{N}$ are in one-to-one correspondence with constants in $\mathbb{N}$.
One minor thing is that for all nullary functions to be primitive recursive, we need to declare that the function $Z \colon \mathbb{N}^0 \to \mathbb{N}$ such that $Z() = 0$ is primitive recurive, or have some other way to get this function, and then all other nullary functions are also primitive recursive as compositions $S(S(\dots S(N())\dots ))$.

In set theory, a function is a set of ordered pairs of the form <argument, value>. For example, addition is the set of pairs of the form <<x,y>,x+y>. Can a function with zero arguments be understood in this way? What would we put as the first element of the pair?

Well, for this we need to encode tuples of arbitrary length. Again, there are various ways to do this. One possible way is to encode a tuple $(x_1, \dots, x_n)$ as the function $x \colon n \to \mathbb{N}$ where the natural numbers $n$ are defined as certain $n$-element sets (usually $0 = \varnothing$, $n = {0, 1, \dots, n - 1}$. In particular, the empty tuple $()$ is then the same as the empty function $\varnothing \to \mathbb{N}$, and the same as the empty set $\varnothing$. So the nullary function with value $c$ looks like ${\langle\varnothing, c \rangle}$.

Shouldn't ${  \langle \emptyset, c \rangle}$ be function ${ \emptyset } \to \mathbb{N}$? An argument of the function should be an element of its domain, not the entire domain. But then it would have one argument, not zero arguments...

The tuple $() = \varnothing$ is a function $\varnothing \to \mathbb{N}$. The function $f \colon \mathbb{N}^0 \to \mathbb{N}$ is a function ${\varnothing} \to \mathbb{N}$.
